# Saving bitmaps to ArrayList makes Bitmaps whole black

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to save bitmaps in an ArrayList. I generate 2 types of bitmaps, they are basically identical - drawn with a finger by the user.

- The first bitmap is fully visible in activity
- The second is stored dynamically in the ArrayList - it is a slice of the last x milliseconds from the visible bitmap - It will be further converting and sending by BT.

The problem is that the last bitmap in the ArrayList is well saved, while each previous bitmap turns into a black rectangle when you add another one.

Relevant code snippets:

```
 private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapsListToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<Canvas> canvasListToSend = new ArrayList<>();

mBitmapToShow = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingWidth,drawingHeight,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            mCanvasToShow = new Canvas(mBitmapToShow);

            bitmapsListToSend.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingWidth,drawingHeight,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565))
//mCanvasToSend = new Canvas(bitmapsListToSend.get(bitmapsListToSend.size()-1));

canvasListToSend.add(new Canvas(bitmapsListToSend.get(bitmapsListToSend.size()-1)));;
```

I tried to make separate Canvas to each bitmap without success

```
public class PaintView extends View {

private final Paint mPaintToShow = new Paint();
private Bitmap mBitmapToShow;
private Canvas mCanvasToShow;

private final Paint mPaintToSend = new Paint();
//private Canvas mCanvasToSend;


private TouchPoint startPoint;

@Nullable
private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapsListToSend = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Canvas> canvasListToSend = new ArrayList<>();

private int bitmapCounter = 0;
private int alpha = 1;

/* debug */
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();

public PaintView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    setFocusable(true);
    mPaintToShow.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaintToShow.setColor(BLACK);
    mPaintToShow.setAlpha(alpha);
    mPaintToShow.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaintToShow.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    mPaintToSend.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaintToSend.setColor(BLACK);
    mPaintToSend.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaintToSend.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    mBitmapToShow = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingWidth,drawingHeight,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    mCanvasToShow = new Canvas(mBitmapToShow);

    bitmapsListToSend.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingWidth,drawingHeight,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565));
    //mCanvasToSend = new Canvas(bitmapsListToSend.get(bitmapsListToSend.size()-1));
    canvasListToSend.add(new Canvas(bitmapsListToSend.get(bitmapsListToSend.size()-1)));

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    mCanvasToShow.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    //mCanvasToSend.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvasListToSend.get(canvasListToSend.size()-1).drawColor(WHITE);
}

public void clear() {
    if (mCanvasToShow != null) {
        mPaintToShow.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mCanvasToShow.drawPaint(mPaintToShow);
        //mCanvasToSend.drawPaint(mPaintToShow);
        bitmapCounter=0;
        alpha=1;
        bitmapsListToSend.clear();
        canvasListToSend.clear();
        mPaintToShow.setColor(BLACK);
        watch.reset();
        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mBitmapToShow != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapToShow, 0, 0, null);
        //mCanvasToSend.drawBitmap(bitmapsListToSend.get(bitmapsListToSend.size()-1), 0, 0, null);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return onTouchOrHoverEvent(event, true /*isTouch*/);
}

private boolean onTouchOrHoverEvent(MotionEvent event, boolean isTouch) {
        /*if (SENDING_NOW)
            return true;*/

    final int action = event.getActionMasked();
    mPaintToShow.setStrokeWidth((float) ( getBrushSize() ));

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        startPoint = new TouchPoint(event, 0);
        runnableSaveBitmaps.run();
        runnableChangeAlpha.run();
        watch.start();
    }else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        runnableChangeAlpha.run();
    }else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        startPoint = new TouchPoint(event, 0);
        handlerSaveBitmaps.removeCallbacks(runnableSaveBitmaps);
        handlerChangeAlpha.removeCallbacks(runnableChangeAlpha);
        watch.stop();
    }

    //make drawings//

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                paintLines(mTouchPoints);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mCanvasToShow.drawCircle(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, getBrushSize()/2f, mPaintToShow);
                //mCanvasToSend.drawCircle(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, getBrushSize()/2f, mPaintToSend);
                canvasListToSend.get(canvasListToSend.size()-1).drawCircle(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, getBrushSize()/2f, mPaintToSend);
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}

//drawing methods//

Handler handlerSaveBitmaps = new Handler();
Runnable runnableSaveBitmaps = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        handlerSaveBitmaps.postDelayed(runnableSaveBitmaps, 10);

        Log.v("B", "Bitmap added " + bitmapCounter + " " + (watch.toString()));
        bitmapsListToSend.add(bitmapCounter, Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingWidth,drawingHeight,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565));
        canvasListToSend.add(bitmapCounter++, new Canvas(bitmapsListToSend.get(bitmapsListToSend.size()-1)));
    }
};

Handler handlerChangeAlpha = new Handler();
Runnable runnableChangeAlpha = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handlerChangeAlpha.postDelayed(runnableChangeAlpha, 635);

        if(alpha < 255)
            mPaintToShow.setAlpha(alpha++);
        else {
            handlerChangeAlpha.removeCallbacks(runnableChangeAlpha);
            Log.v("A", "ALPHA MAX" + (watch.toString()));
        }

    }
};
```

}

If Runnable saves 100 bitmaps - 99 will be black, the last one will be ok

//Bitmap.copy() fixed it

Comment: `it is a slice of the last x milliseconds from the visible bitmap ` Bitmaps have no milli seconds or seconds or anything to do with time. Please explain better what you have.

Comment: You should store in the list copies of the original bitmap, use Bitmap.copy method for that.

Comment: I edited the post with more code, deleted methods that makes drawing and works fine

Comment: @Alex will try that

Comment: Bitmap.copy() worked 
Thanks!